# In Node.js, why doesn't it execute the command of an if condition?

Tags: mysql, node.js, if-statement

I'm just at the beginning of learning JS and Node.js, so I can't seem to wrap my mind around this issue.

The script queries a MYSQL, returns a list of companies.

Then for each company, it calls an API for financial data.

If there are financial data, it inserts them into the DB.
If there are no financial data, it should insert into the DB with value 0, **but it doesn't**.

Everything works except the case when there are no financial data.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
fetch = require('node-fetch');


var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "host.ip",
  user: "user_name",
  password: "pass_word",
  database: "db_db"

});
var  years_to_scrape = [2021,2020,2019,2018];

connection.query("SELECT t1.CUI,t1.Denumire_Companie,Reg_Com,Status,Localitate FROM Date_Companii as t1 LEFT JOIN Date_Financiare as t2 ON t2.cui = t1.cui WHERE t2.AN IS NULL ORDER by t1.CUI DESC LIMIT 3", function(error,results,fields) {
  if (error) { return console.error(error.message);}


  //console.log(results)
  var db_results = results;
  //console.log(db_results);

  for (i in db_results) {
    var one_after_another = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(db_results[i]));
    console.log(one_after_another.CUI);

    for (i in years_to_scrape){

  var url = 'https://webservicesp.anaf.ro/bilant?an=' + years_to_scrape[i]+ '&cui=' + one_after_another.CUI;
  
   fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then (json => {
      console.log(json)
      var r = json;
      console.log(r)

      var indicatori = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(r.i))
      console.log (indicatori)


      if (indicatori.length==0){
       
  connection.query('INSERT INTO Date_Financiare(CUI,AN,Numar_Salariati,Pierdere_Neta,Profit_Net,Pierdere_Bruta,Profit_Brut,Cheltuieli_Totale,Venituri_Totale,Cifra_De_Afacere_Neta,Patrimoniul_Regiei,Capital_Subscris_Varsat,Capitaluri_Total,Provizioane,Venituri_In_Avans,Datorii,Cheltuieli_In_Avans,Casa_Si_Conturi,Creante,Stocuri,Active_Circulante,Active_Mobilizate,CAEN) VALUES ('+cuiul+","+anul+',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);', function(error,results,fields) {
  if (error) { /*return console.error(error.message)*/;}
  if(results){/*return console.log("results");*/}
    if(fields){/*return console.log("fields");*/}
    console.log("Inserted into DB");

      })}
      else{

         var anul = r.an;
         console.log("Anul: "+ anul)
         var cuiul = r.cui;
         console.log("CUI: "+ cuiul)
         var caen = r.caen;
         console.log("CAEN: "+caen)

        for (z in indicatori){
          if(indicatori[z].indicator === "I1"){
      var valoare_active_mobilizate = indicatori[z].val_indicator;
    }else if(indicatori[z].indicator === "I2"){
      var valoare_active_circulante = indicatori[z].val_indicator;
    }else if(indicatori[z].indicator === "I3"){
      var valoare_stocuri = indicatori[z].val_indicator;
    }else if(indicatori[z].indicator === "I4"){
      var valoare_creante = indicatori[z].val_indicator;
    }else if(indicatori[z].indicator === "I5"){
      var valoare_casa_si_conturi = indicatori[z].val_indicator;
    }else if(indicatori[z].indicator === "I6"){
      var valoare_cheltuieli_in_avans = indicatori[z].val_indicator;
    }else if(indicatori[z].indicator === "I7"){
      var valoare_datorii = indicatori[z].val_indicator;
    }else if(indicatori[z].indicator === "I8"){
      var valoare_venituri_in_avans = indicatori[z].val_indicator;
    }else if(indicatori[z].indicator === "I9"){
      var valoare_provizioane = indicatori[z].val_indicator;
    }else if(indicatori[z].indicator === "I10"){
      var valoare_capitaluri_total = indicatori[z].val_indicator;
    }else if(indicatori[z].indicator === "I11"){
      var valoare_capital_subscris_varsat = indicatori[z].val_indicator;
    }else if(indicatori[z].indicator === "I12"){
      var valoare_patrimoniul_regiei = indicatori[z].val_indicator;
    }else if(indicatori[z].indicator === "I13"){
      var valoare_cifra_de_afacere_neta = indicatori[z].val_indicator;
    }else if(indicatori[z].indicator === "I14"){
      var valoare_venituri_totale = indicatori[z].val_indicator;
    }else if(indicatori[z].indicator === "I15"){
      var valoare_cheltuieli_totale = indicatori[z].val_indicator;
    }else if(indicatori[z].indicator === "I16"){
      var valoare_profit_brut = indicatori[z].val_indicator;
    }else if(indicatori[z].indicator === "I17"){
      var valoare_pierdere_bruta = indicatori[z].val_indicator;
    }else if(indicatori[z].indicator === "I18"){
      var valoare_profit_net = indicatori[z].val_indicator;
    }else if(indicatori[z].indicator === "I19"){
      var valoare_pierdere_neta = indicatori[z].val_indicator;
    }else if(indicatori[z].indicator === "I20"){
      var valoare_numar_salariati = indicatori[z].val_indicator;
    }else{Console.log("Error")};
     connection.query("INSERT INTO Date_Financiare(CUI,AN,Numar_Salariati,Pierdere_Neta,Profit_Net,Pierdere_Bruta,Profit_Brut,Cheltuieli_Totale,Venituri_Totale,Cifra_De_Afacere_Neta,Patrimoniul_Regiei,Capital_Subscris_Varsat,Capitaluri_Total,Provizioane,Venituri_In_Avans,Datorii,Cheltuieli_In_Avans,Casa_Si_Conturi,Creante,Stocuri,Active_Circulante,Active_Mobilizate,CAEN) VALUES ("+cuiul+","+anul+","+valoare_numar_salariati+","+valoare_pierdere_neta+","+valoare_profit_net+","+valoare_pierdere_bruta+","+valoare_profit_brut+","+valoare_cheltuieli_totale+","+valoare_venituri_totale+","+valoare_cifra_de_afacere_neta+","+valoare_patrimoniul_regiei+","+valoare_capital_subscris_varsat+","+valoare_capitaluri_total+","+valoare_provizioane+","+valoare_venituri_in_avans+","+valoare_datorii+","+valoare_cheltuieli_in_avans+","+valoare_casa_si_conturi+","+valoare_creante+","+valoare_stocuri+","+valoare_active_circulante+","+valoare_active_mobilizate+","+caen+");", function(error,results,fields) {
  if (error) { /*return console.error(error.message);*/}

      })

     

    }}})}}});
```

Can someone help with the logic behind my error? Why isn't it pushing values into the DB when there are no financial data?

Here's an example of the response from a DB query

`"SELECT t1.CUI,t1.Denumire_Companie,Reg_Com,Status,Localitate FROM Date_Companii as t1 LEFT JOIN Date_Financiare as t2 ON t2.cui = t1.cui WHERE t2.AN IS NULL ORDER by t1.CUI DESC LIMIT 3"`

```
[
  RowDataPacket {
    CUI: 2147483647,
    Denumire_Companie: 'Company Name 1',
    Reg_Com: 'F40/2569/2003',
    Status: 1048,
    Localitate: null
  },
  RowDataPacket {
    CUI: 45892171,
    Denumire_Companie: 'Company Name 2',
    Reg_Com: 'J6/342/2022',
    Status: 1048,
    Localitate: 'Municipiul Bistriţa'
  },
  RowDataPacket {
    CUI: 45892163,
    Denumire_Companie: 'Company Name 3',
    Reg_Com: 'J6/340/2022',
    Status: 1048,
    Localitate: 'Loc. Viişoara'
  }
]
```

Comment: maybe it would help if you didn't comment out the error logging to see if there is an actual error thrown ... In many of such cases the problem comes from creating queries by string concatenation. Don't do that. Have a look at the docs of your library and check how to create a parameterized query. This will make your code less error prone, more secure and easier to maintain ...

Answer (score 0):

Congrats on starting NodeJS there !

You just discovered the hell of synchronicity versus asynchronicity in Javascript

Your question "*Why it's not inserting ?*" is basically unanswerable because the result of your code is unpredictable due to asynchronicity nature and misusage in your case.

To start digging into it, run this :

```js
function promiseTimeout(t, val) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve) {
       setTimeout(function() {
           resolve(val);
       }, t);
   });
}

// Asynchronous, with callback
setTimeout(() => console.log('3'), 3000)

// Asynchronous, with promise
promiseTimeout(2000).then(() => console.log('2'))

// Synchronous
console.log('1')
```

Understand the result, then you might be able to fix your code

Answer (score -1):

```
let mysql = require('mysql');
let axios = require('axios');

let connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'host',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'pass',
    database: 'db bame',
    port: 'port'
});


connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error('error: ' + err.message);
    }

    console.log('Connected to the MySQL server.');

    connection.query('select * from your_table', (err, rows) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        console.log("data received from database")
        rows.map(row => {
            const fieldName = row['field_name_from_db']
            console.log(fieldName)

            const url = 'https://webservicesp.anaf.ro/bilant?an=' + '2019' + '&cui=' + fieldName;
            axios.get(url)
                .then(res => {
                    console.log("Got response", res.data)
                    //here do your login then insert/update logic


                })
                .catch(err => console.log("ERR RESPONSE"))
        })
        connection.destroy()
    })
  });
```

Comment: Code only answers are highly discouraged. Please explain why your anwer presumably solves the problem ...